# Pyspark create a dataframe from a case object

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying using the code below to create a dataframe. But, it doesn't work. Could anyone show me how to make it work. Many thanks.

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    id: float
    name: str    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    rawdata = [Person(1, "Test01"), Person(2, "Test02"), Person(3, "Test03")]
    rdd = sc.parallelize(rawdata)
    
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, [Person])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the spark session as follows:

```
rawdata = [Person(1, "Test01"), Person(2, "Test02"), Person(3, "Test03")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rawdata, ["person"])
```